# How to fixed UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED ERRORS INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: community, flow

I have assign all permission related to ticket object, profile and user.
I have also searched in google and follow step but issue is still in flow.

Note:

I have fill textbox then click next button Ticket is created but ownerid not update.
Salesforce internal is working fine but issue on portal.
please suggest .[issues first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbkuk.jpg)[![issues second][2]][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Customer Community, community users can only own their own Cases. That would appear to be your issue based on what you're telling us about this working for you with internal users. Several references you may want to look at are [Getting Started with Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/), [Salesforce Security Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/) and [Communities User Licenses](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) (note that community users can't create cases for others).